# Control my computer camera with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, camera

Is there a way to control the computer camera (activate) using javascript (preferably jQuery)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use the [getUserMedia](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/) API.

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=getUserMedia) is, at the time of writing, limited to Opera 12.

Your other options would involve using something like Flash, which has access to webcams, to write a JavaScript bridge.

Comment: Google Chrome Canary also supports getUserMedia

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll read a little more about that, but i guess that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Browser api's for cameras are basically unsupported. Unfortunately you will have to use flash to do that in any kind of cross browser compatible way. But fret not, there is jQuery pluggin that uses a simple flash object to expose the camera to javascript.

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/